# findByAttribute in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-tools

Im using `Ember v1.0.0,` `Ember-Data v1.0.0-beta.3` and building using `Ember-tools.`

Inside my `order_controller`, I've got an action called: `delivered`. Once triggered, I want to make some changes to the current object (no problems here) -- but I also want to query an object from this same model and make some changes to it.

Heres my ObjectController:

```
var OrderController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
actions: {
    edit: function(){
        this.transitionToRoute('order.edit');
    },
    delivered: function(){
        // orders are sorted by "sequence" attr.
        var current_sequence = this.get('sequence');

        // find the next order in pipeline
        var next_sequence = current_sequence+=1;

        // HERE is the challenge!
        var next_order = App.Order.find({sequence: next_sequence});

        this.set('up_next', false);

        next_order.set('up_next', true);

        this.transitionToRoute('order', next_order.id)

    }
}
```

});

module.exports = OrderController;

Im using FIXTURES:

```
Order.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "John Doe",
        email: "john@doe.com",
        telephone: "263663636",
        address: "123 Example Rd.",
            ......
        sequence: 4,
        done: false,
        up_next: false
    },
```

Basically Im looking for a way to query records from inside the ObjectController with more specific attributes than just ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Find all the records, find returns a promise
    var promise = this.get('store').find('order');

    this.set('up_next', false);

    next_order.set('up_next', true);

    // once the promise is resolved
    promise.then(function(records){

      // filter out the first item to satisfy the method passed into it
      // http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_find
      var filteredRecord = records.find( function(record){ return record.get('sequence')==sequenceNo;});
      this.transitionToRoute('order', next_order)
    }
```